# Firebase userDisplay name and UserPhotoUri

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

When I get from FirebaseUser username and UserPhotoURI 
username = null
UsePhotoUri = null

This is my code for Registration

```
rAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username,password_user).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    rAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username,password_user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                FirebaseUser userFire = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                                UserProfileChangeRequest updateprofile  = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                        .setDisplayName(userName.getText().toString().trim())
                                        .setPhotoUri(userphotourl).build();
                                userFire.updateProfile(updateprofile);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    SingIn(view);
                }
                else{Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Не удалось зарегистрироваться пжалуйта проверьте подключение к интернету",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
            }
        });
```

Why my displayname = null

In this code I read user account

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_actv);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        USER = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        Toast.makeText(this,mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName() + " " + mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ProfileName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PName);
        ProfileEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PEmail);
        ProfileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        UpdateProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.UProfile);
        if(USER != null)
        {
            ProfileName.setText(USER.getDisplayName());
            ProfileEmail.setText(USER.getEmail());
            ProfileImage.setImageURI(USER.getPhotoUrl());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to get `userDisplayName` and `userPhotoUri` from `Firebase` ?

Comment: from firebase.getcurrentuser

Comment: Your code only shows you **setting** the display name. Please also show the code that where you are reading the display name and **getting** `null` and (*importantly*) how that code relates to the code you already shared.